# Get value of the first value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to get the value of the first value pair from a form submission via AJAX. Here’s what the var Formdata looks like (id=4&name=somename&blah=blah). How do I get the id value of 4? As you can see I was trying several ways but had no luck. Any suggestion would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
$("#updatetask").validate({     
    submitHandler: function() {
    var formdata = $('#updatetask').serialize();
    var fistkey = formdata.split("&",1);
    var tester = fistkey.slice(-1);
    alert(tester);
    /*
   $.post('/tasks/AJAXupdate', $('#updatetask').serialize(), function(data){
    var returnMsg = data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    if (returnMsg == 'error'){
        alert(returnMsg+': Unable to update task.');
    }else{
        parent.$.fancybox.close();
    }
   });*/
return false;
    }       
});


});
```

Comment: Are you only interested in the first key/value pair of the url or of the `id` parameter specifically? What if id is not the first? Do you still want to use it?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: They are related, but I don't think it should be considered a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you simply `$('#updatetask :input:eq(0)').val()` instead of serializing it and parsing the string?